# How can you test if you're on the homepage in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm working on a Joomla site, and I need the front page to look slightly different from the rest of the pages, but not enough to warrant the use of two themes (it's a pain to have to update two stylesheets and two sets of images every time I want to make a small change).

My thoughts are to throw in a little test in the index.php of the template: if we're at the homepage, serve X, otherwise, serve Y. However, I'm not entirely sure how to test this. I can't just use the URL because url.com/ and url.com/index.php and url.com/index.php? etc etc are all valid.

Does anyone know of a way to do what I'm trying to do? Like a $_JOOMLA['page'] variable or something convenient like that?

Thanks!
--Mala

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(JRequest::getVar('view') == "frontpage" ) {
    //You are in!
}
else {
    //You are out!
}
```

Comment: This might break if you install another component that has a view named "frontpage". To make sure you're looking at the content component, I would write the 'if' statement this way: if(JRequest::getVar('view') == 'frontpage' && JRequest::getVar('option') == 'com_content')

Comment: It works if you're using the com_content frontpage view on the front page, and not another component.

Comment: @Soufiane-Hassou Perhaps I'm missing something. This returns false for me. Is there some prerequisite for this to work? BTW, this is for my own template that I've built by hand. Thanks

Comment: Your template has nothing to do with what page is considered the "home" page. The home page in Joomla is determined by the menu item that is flagged as the default page. The answer below by happyproff is what you want to use as it determines the home page by checking if the page you are on matches the menu item flagged as the default page.

Comment: As others pointed out, this only works if you use a featured layout as your homepage. Even a vanilla install of Joomla with sample data doesn't do that.

Answer (score 7):

To be shure that client is on homepage, you should test "is current page (Itemid) choosen as default menu item" like this code do (for Joomla 1.6, 1.7 and 2.5):

```
<?php
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    echo 'This is the front page';
}
?>
```

To find code for Joomla 1.5, look to http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

Answer (score 6):

This works for me, i had trouble using any other way

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
if ($app->getMenu()->getActive()->home) {
    $homepage=true;
}
```

Comment: I'm stumped. I've built my own little template. Nothing much. But to check for the home page, only your method worked (not the one by Soufiane Hassou. Would you know why? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that Soufiane Hassou's way works for joomla 1.5, mine is tested on 2.5.. my way prob wont work in joomla 1.5. i'd have to test it to see. The way I provided also works with multiple languages. Joomla 1.5 isnt made in the same way for multiples languages.

Answer (score 3):

For Joomla 2.5 and 3.x use the following code for a site with single language:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    echo 'This is homepage';
}
?>
```

For multi-lingual sites, detecting homepage (front page) depends on the currently selected language, so you will need to use something like the following:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault( 'en-GB' )) {
    echo 'This is English homepage';
}
elseif ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault( 'it-IT' )) {
    echo 'This is Italian homepage';
}
?>
```

For multi-lingual sites, you can also use the following code:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault($lang->getTag())) {
    echo 'This is homepage';
}
else {
    echo 'This is not homepage';
}
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works perfectly, also nice explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

for Joomla 1.6 and 1.7 it would be as follows:

```
if(JRequest::getVar('view') == "featured" ) {
    //You are in!
}
else {
    //You are out!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Joomla .6, nothing else than the [this](http://www.toolboxcreations.com/articles/templating/9-template-tricks-testing-for-the-front-page) worked for me:

Answer (score 1):

also you could define every page:

```
<?php 
$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
?>
 <body class="<?php echo $active->alias; ?> ">
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault($lang->getTag())) {
        echo 'This is the front page';
}
else {
        echo 'Accueil';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.x to show some content only on frontpage You can use

```
<?php $menu = JSite::getMenu();
    if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) : ?>
Some code here to show only on front page
<?php endif ?>
```

And to show something everywhere except frontpage just negate !=

```
<?php $menu = JSite::getMenu();
    if ($menu->getActive() != $menu->getDefault()) : ?>
    Some code here to show everywhere except frontpage
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As R.B. already pointed out, it's sensible to check the language of the menu item also, just in case there is more than one 'homepage' as their is in multi-lingual sites.

```
<?php // Determine if we are on the homepage
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$langTag = $lang ? JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag() : null;

$isHomepage = $langTag ? ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault($langTag)) : ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()); ?>
```

Then where you want homepage-only content:

```
<?php if ($isHomepage) : ?>
     <div class="homepage-markup">

     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```